# howto purge and view haproxy cache

Tags: haproxy

I have a haproxy 1.9.4 running on CentOS 7 machine with the following configuration

```
backend test
   acl is_cached path_end .js .css
   http-request cache-use static if is_cached
   http-response cache-store static if is_cached
   server my_webserver 127.0.0.1 check
cache static
    total-max-size 512
    max-age 300s
```

So is there way to purge cache without restarting haproxy?

How can I view cache?

Comment: [nuster](https://github.com/jiangwenyuan/nuster) a cache server based on haproxy supports purge

Comment: Reloading the haproxy service purges the cache according to my tests.
This is not the same as restarting. The reload command uses the graceful stop to try to seamlessly reload the config without donwtime.

Comment: For viewing the cache, the documentation states that:

> It's possible to view the status of a cache using the Unix socket command
"show cache" consult section 9.3 "Unix Socket commands" of Management Guide
for more details.

I don't know what "show cache" means, but it may be what you are looking for,

ref: https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/latest/onepage/#6